# Error: In next.js app Command "npm run build" exited with 1 while deploying to vercel in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my project to the vercel but it is giving me error.
the erros are at the stack of vercel

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at P (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:666336)
at l (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:661527)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662728
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662701
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at a (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662521)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662785
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at l (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662478)
Error occurred prerendering page "/review/reviewyourpurchases". Read 
more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at P (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:666336)
at l (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:661527)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662728
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662701
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at a (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662521)
at /vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662785
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at l (/vercel/path0/flipkartclone/.next/server/chunks/1275.js:1:662478)
⚠ Entire page /search deopted into client-side rendering. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering /search

✓ Generating static pages (50/50) 
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
/faq/page: /faq
/login/page: /login
/orders/page: /orders
/review/reviewyourpurchases/page: /review/reviewyourpurchases
 Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Please guide me how can i overcome with this i am trying to overcome it from last 2 days but did not find any solution.